# fgets() malfunction

Tags: php

Anyone can show me why this piece of code works with the second line but not the first line, although they are the same?

Here is the pass.txt file:

```
01234567 5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99
01234567 5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99
```

Here's the code:

```
<?php
    $f = fopen("pass.txt", "r");
    if ($f) {
        $buffer = fgets($f);
        $buffer = fgets($f); //Comment out this line to read the first line

        $token = explode(' ', $buffer);
        if ($token[1] == hash('md5', 'password'))
            echo "Password correct";
        else
            echo "Password incorrect";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @David Schwartz pointed out, the most possible reason is the newline character.

You could use `file` function to ignore the newline char.

```
foreach (file('pass.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES) as $line) {
    $token = explode(' ', $line);
    if ($token[1] == hash('md5', 'password'))
      echo "Password correct";
    else
      echo "Password incorrect";
}
```

If the file is very large, then use `fgets` to read it one by one and trim the newline.

Answer (score 2):

Your first line is terminated by a newline character and your second line is not. Since your hash doesn't include a newline character, it won't match the first line.

> Reading ends when length - 1 bytes have been read, on a newline (**which is included in the return value**), or on EOF (whichever comes first). If no length is specified, it will keep reading from the stream until it reaches the end of the line. - [fgets documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php)